# Querying the connecting device for usb devices in OS X

Tags: python, macos, usb

Ok, so here's the setup. In OS X (>= 10.5), is it possible, given a mounted usb device with a known location, say /Volumes/FLASHDRIVE, to find out whether this device is connecting through another usb device (a card reader for example) and if so, which one.

Ideally, this could all be done in python, but if not that's ok too.

Comment: I developed a OSX application that listening the USB devices that connected from OSX and application runs fine before submit to app store. At the time of submission to app store I enabled the "App Sandbox" and enabled USB in App Sandbox. But after enable this application is not able to get the list of USB connected devices. I am using peertalk library from github. Link is below:

PeerTalk

So now please can anyone suggest the solution for this. or suggest any option to get the devices list which is connected from osx using USB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the term *device* with the term *volume*--in this example (and in most real world situations) there would only be one device involved.

The state of most hardware falls under the purview of IOKit, and the only way you can possibly get to this information from Python is through careful parsing of the **ioreg** tool's output.